# Finding the vector with a given component

Tags: vector-analysis

When questions goes like "the horizontal velocity is ...", that is referring to the x-component of the vector, correct me if I'm wrong. But I need the vector, is it possible to find the vector from just one of the component? If so, what steps do I take to do that?

Comment: To find an $n$-dimensional vector you need $n$ numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't absolutely necessary that a horizontal component refers to the x-axis. But in most cases with simple math, this is what they're referring to. If a vector has more than one component, and the only information you are given is one component, then you cannot construct the vector. You simply don't have enough information.

If the only component of your vector is in the horizontal direction, then you would say it has a component of $X$ in the $\hat{i}$ direction. Where $X$ could be a variable, or it could actually be a number they give you. Your vector could look like so:

$\vec{v}= 5 \hat{i}$